# Spring / Hibernate / JUnit - No Hibernate Session bound to Thread

Tags: hibernate, spring, junit

I'm trying to access the current hibernate session in a test case, and getting the following error:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: No
>   Hibernate Session bound to thread, and
>   configuration does not allow creation
>   of non-transactional one here     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:63)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:574)

I've clearly missed some sort of setup, but not sure what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  This is my first crack at Hibernate / Spring etc, and the learning curve is certainly steep!

Code follows:

The offending class:

```
public class DbUnitUtil extends BaseDALTest {
    @Test
    public void exportDtd() throws Exception
    {

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        session.beginTransaction();
        Connection hsqldbConnection = session.connection(); 

        IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(hsqldbConnection);

        // write DTD file
        FlatDtdDataSet.write(connection.createDataSet(), new FileOutputStream("test.dtd"));
    }
}
```

Base class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public class BaseDALTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {
    public BaseDALTest()
    {
        super();
    }
        @Resource
        protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:hsqldb:mem:sample</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>sa</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value></value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="com.foo.spring.AutoAnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="entityPackages">
            <list>
                <value>com.sample.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="schemaUpdate">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Wrong, that will just fill your code with session management code.

First, add a transaction management bean in your context:

```
    <bean id="transactionManager" 
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

The second thing, extend AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests

```
    public class BaseDALTest 
           extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{
```

Third thing, annotate you test class with

```
    @TransactionConfiguration
    @Transactional
```

If your transaction demarcation is correct(surrounding your dao or service) you should be done.

It's not nice to sprinkle session and transaction handling code all around your code (even inside your tests).

Comment: Ideally you should have @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) if you are testing some dao/repository tests which are themselves not annotated with transactions since they depend upon the class which initiated to be in transaction. On @TransactionConfiguration tell it about your transaction manager @TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager",
  defaultRollback = true)

Comment: I just read your post and I managed to overcome the problem for me. Now I don't see new lines in tables though while no error is thrown. I assume I have some how to stop rollback?

Answer (score 5):

Please refer to the Spring documentation. There is a whole chapter on testing, and a section on transaction management:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testing-tx

I've had success extending AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests, but there's a workaround:

```
TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
    @Override
    protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
        // DAO has access to the session through sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        myDao.findSomething(id);
    }
});
```

Comment: I found the dependency on AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests quite restrictive, so I really your TransactionTemplate suggestion - it works!

Answer (score 2):

With the above Spring configuration, it should be sufficient to code

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

in your method and class to test. Session management is done by the Hibernate / Spring /JUnit test configuration, as later is done in the Hibernate / Spring configuration in the *real* application.

This is how it worked for my tests. In the final web application there will automatically be a Hibernate session associated with the current web request and therefore in testing there should be no `sessionFactory.openSession()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Duh.

> Session session =
>   <del>sessionFactory.openSession();</del>

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

Oops.

(Edited since this was wrong, and getting upvoted).

Comment: actually, this is totally wrong.  You want to call getCurrentSession() otherwise you will be responsible for closing it and your transactions won't work with the annotation driven model.

Comment: @Justin - Thanks, the post has been updated based on this feedback.  @ Downvoter - care to comment why?  (This post has been updated for over a year!)

Answer (score 0):

Spring ignores `hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread` property (**which you don't use**) and  wraps Hibernate’s `SessionFactory` in it's own transactional version as explained [here](http://www.theresearchkitchen.com/archives/73)

The solution to this is to set the property

```
<property name="exposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory"><value>false</value></property>
```

in session factory bean configuration