# autowire hibernate session with spring 3 and hibernate 4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to do: `@Autowire Session session`. For hibernate 3, the process is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500775/proper-way-to-autowire-a-hibernate-session-in-a-spring-transaction-junit-test). it uses ...hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.getSession. but in spring 3.2 there is no such method in ...hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils

Comment: You can inject `SessionFactory` and use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`

Comment: yes, i know but it's just... too verbose. if i can inject entityManager with jpa then i should be able to inject session with some proxy mechanism. i just don't know how... yet :)

Answer (score 4):

Great changes have taken place in Spring3.x, a few days ago I met the same problem, Through the offical document we know that Spring won't provide HibernateTemplate and HibernateDaoSupport any longer, we are advised to use Hibernate pure API, and about your confusion here is my solution:

first, define a sessionFactory bean in applicationContext.xml,

```
<!--  sessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.bbs.*.entity</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    ${hibernate.dialect}
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">${hibernate.connection.autocommit}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/bbs</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">root</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">123456</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and then, in your DAO

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

in this way you'll get the hibernate session, then do what you want, just enjoy it:)