# How to acquire current session in transactional @Test for SpringBoot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, junit, spring-test

[Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx-annotation-demo) warns about **False Positives** in `Transactional` tests and suggest the following:

```java
// ...

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Transactional
@Test // no expected exception!
public void falsePositive() {
    updateEntityInHibernateSession();
    // False positive: an exception will be thrown once the Hibernate
    // Session is finally flushed (i.e., in production code)
}

@Transactional
@Test(expected = ...)
public void updateWithSessionFlush() {
    updateEntityInHibernateSession();
    // Manual flush is required to avoid false positive in test
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
}

// ...
```

I have the following base class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public abstract class BaseSpringBootTest {
```

and a class that extends it where I want to apply this practice of injecting the `sessionFactory`:

```
public class EmployeeRepositoryTest extends BaseSpringBootTest {

  @Autowired
  SessionFactory sessionFactory
```

but I am getting:

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available
```

I also tried injecting

```
@Autowired
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
```

and then calling:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

but this throws the following Exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
```

How do I get a reference to `currentSession` in a test, so that I can finally call:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
```

as documented in Spring Boot documentation?

Comment: That isn't the Spring Boot documentation that is the Spring documentation. Which is a different thing!. Just inject the `EntityManager` as Spring Boot by default uses JPA.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you, fixed the question. I was just tired I guess. The problem with injecting `EntityManager` is, the thrown exception is not `DataIntegrityViolationException` but rather `PersistenceException`. I guess it is ok, it is the closest I can get to real behaviour..

Comment: You won't get a `DataIntegrityViolationException` with a `Session` either as direct use of the persistence implementation bypasses the Spring exception handling for data access technologies.

Comment: Did  you try      `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().flush();`?

Comment: Are you aware of this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500775/proper-way-to-autowire-a-hibernate-session-in-a-spring-transaction-junit-test it seems to be a solution.

Comment: @Tr1monster these answers are from 2009 so i'm not sure they're really valid anymore

Comment: @bharal, have you tried to also add `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` to your `BaseSpringBootTest` class??

Comment: Also, @bharal. please try moving all your annotations from your abstract class to `EmployeeRepositoryTest`. idk what java version you're using... but Java inherit annotations only since v9+, your issue might be related to that...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to read on/little scroll:

> The following example shows matching methods for **JPA**:

> ```java
> @PersistenceContext EntityManager entityManager;
>
> @Transactional
> @Test // no expected exception!
> public void falsePositive() {
>     updateEntityInJpaPersistenceContext();
>     // False positive: an exception will be thrown once the JPA
>     // EntityManager is finally flushed (i.e., in production code)
> }
>
> @Transactional
> @Test(expected = ...)
> public void updateWithEntityManagerFlush() {
>     updateEntityInJpaPersistenceContext();
>     // Manual flush is required to avoid false positive in test
>     entityManager.flush();
> }
> ```

This should solve (all) your:

> `org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!`

..problems.

Comment: im curious how to get the current session, or failing that to avoid the hibernate exception. sorry, but i don't quite understand the answer you've posted - it is some code but i don't quite see what the solution is, and you seem to be quoting something, but i'm not sure what?

Comment: I am quoting your link ... the solution (i think) is: to stick to "jpa" classes (not "hibernate")

Comment: and `entityManager.flush();` is equivalent for (the desired) `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();`

Comment: oh i didn't ask the question so i don't know what link you refer to - but i take it it is the "spring documentation" mentioned at the beginning?

Comment: sry, my bad... correct [this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx-annotation-demo) ..little scrolling/ctrl+f 
 and m.d.'s comment "Just inject the EntityManager as *Spring Boot by default uses JPA.*"