# No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

Tags: java, hibernate

What is this error about? "**No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here**".
My spring config file looks something like this.

```
<bean id="jndiDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:/devDS</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="stsaDBFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jndiDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>xx.yy.zz.User</value>
            <value>xx.yy.UserResponse</value>

        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbmddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- ################################### Aspects ################################################## -->

<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="stsaDBFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

All the DAO test passes when i test them outside of the container using junit. When I deploy it in jBoss as a portal app,I get this exception. Also it works fine if i remove the portal specific configuration and make it a simple web app and deploy it on jboss.Any idea?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734614/spring-hibernate-junit-no-hibernate-session-bound-to-thread

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have defined a TransactionManager in your spring config but you are trying to execute a hibernate query in a method that is not transactional. Try adding @Transactional to your method or class.

Comment: Its just a select query. Do i have to add this annotation to all DAO methods?

Comment: It can be on the DAO method or on the service method or on either of the classes, but it has to be somewhere in the stack if you're using a TransactionManager or you will get the exception you encountered because you are trying to run a query outside of a transaction.

Comment: Possibly they are being run from a context where no TransactionManager has been defined?

Comment: It can work without annotations as, by default, transaction demarcation is expected to be defined in configuration, unless the <tx:annotation-driven/> element is used (see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained)

Comment: I don't think adding a `@Transacional` to each method and/or class is the right solution here.

Answer (score 4):

I got around this problem by specifying the `current_session_context_class` in `hibernate config` to be "`thread`", as per the simple configuration shown in the [hibernate configuration documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp-configuration).

But it recommends that its not safe for production usage.

Trying to add the following in your `hibernate config` should also help:

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
```

Check out http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/architecture.html#architecture-current-session for more details.

Comment: Just a warning to those who try this and are using Spring: I just got a different error when configuring 'current_session_context_class'. In several other  questions this gave way to problems with transactions. Effectively this seems to remove spring transaction management. (see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293098/how-to-integrate-spring-with-hibernate-session-and-transaction-management)

Comment: I also had different behavior.  I loaded an object from the database, made a change, then tried to persist it.  In order for it to work I had to evict it from the session then save.