# Spring + hibernate 3 "No Hibernate Session bound to thread" But i have a transaction manager configured

Tags: spring, transactions, hibernate3

i have this problem:  "No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here". I'm using spring + hibernate 3. I already had checking this in other questions, but they don´t solve my problem. Here,  my applicationContext of Spring.

```
`<bean id="ServGenerico" class="servico.AbsServicoGenerico" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    p:driverClass="${jdbc.driver}" p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc.url}" p:user="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" p:max PoolSize="10" p:minPoolSize="5" p:maxStatements="0" destroy-method="close"> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" 
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="dao.impl" /> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="servico" />

    <bean id="grupoDeAcaoDao" class="dao.impl.GrupoDeAcaoDao" />
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="dados" />        
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</prop>
                 --><!-- <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">2</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">5000</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">2</prop> -->
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">
                             org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform
                </prop> -->
            </props>
        </property>     
</bean>`
```

My service

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ServGrupoDeAcao extends AbsServicoGenerico<GrupoDeAcao>
{

    public ServGrupoDeAcao()
    {
        super();
        setDao(new GrupoDeAcaoDao());
    }

    public ServGrupoDeAcao(Class<?> clazz)
    {
        super(clazz);       
    }   

    /*@Autowired
    @Qualifier("grupoDeAcaoDao")
    public void setDao(GrupoDeAcaoDao dao)
    {
        super.setDao(dao);
    }*/
}
```

And my DAO

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class GrupoDeAcaoDao extends AbsDao<GrupoDeAcao, Long>
{

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }   

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }   

    @Override
    public Object executarConsultaPersonalizada(NomeMetodo nome,
            Parametros parametros)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public boolean daoCompativel(Class<?> clazz)
    {
        return GrupoDeAcao.class.equals(clazz);
    }
```

The class AbsDao is a generic class that have in your methods, save, update e etc.
And this class have the @Repository and @Transactional Anotations

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293098/how-to-integrate-spring-with-hibernate-session-and-transaction-management

Comment: my problem is another. As I said the problem is in the method getCurrentSession, not transactions

Comment: I put in web.xml the OpenSessionInViewFilter and works, but my DAO don´t persist em DB. What is wrong?