# merge is not valid without active transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

I am creating a standalone Unit test (which uses Spring to AutoWire a few dependencies) to test the functionality of a function in a 3rd party JAR.

The function that is to be tested is "updateRule" which updates an entity in the DB. From the code i can see that this function uses "@Transactional" annotation. (Cant share the 3rd party JAR here)

However, on running the test the updateRule function fails with 
"merge is not valid without active transaction"

I believe i have correctly configured my Spring Setup to activate the @Transactional annotation in the function's implementation as follows :

1)Spring Configuration[Edited to use LocalSessionFactoryBean of Spring] :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {RulesServiceImpl.class, RulesDaoImpl.class})
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager createHibernateTxnMgr(){
        HibernateTransactionManager txnMgr = new  HibernateTransactionManager();
        txnMgr.setSessionFactory(sessionFactoryBean().getObject());     
        return txnMgr;
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("hibernate.cfg.xml"));
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

}
```

2)Junit Test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringConfig.class)
public class TestAppContextCration {

    @Autowired
    private IRulesService rulesService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Rule rule = new Rule();
        rulesService.updateRule(rule);
    }

}
```

3)hibernate util thats used :

```
 public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

**My Configuration :**

Spring : spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE

Note : The AutoWiring is working fine as i confirmed on debugging the test.

Comment: Delete your `HibernateUtil` class and use Spring to configure your `SessionFactory`. Spring needs to integrate with hibernate for proper tx management.

Comment: Doesn't the setup of sessionFactory in the TransactionManager Creation take care of this? As in the SpringConfig. java class above?

Comment: No. Spring needs to set the current session context property and that isn't done by the transaction manager.

Comment: to be sure, this is the line i was referring to :

txnMgr.setSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory());

Comment: Yes I know which line it is.

Comment: Updated the config. , still fails with the same. I noticed that transactionManager in sessionFactory is Null. Looks like its still not working...

Comment: Post your hibernate configuration (although I would recommend ditching in and configure it in java or xml instead).

Comment: Its Working after removing the line 
    

<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property> 

as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293098/how-to-integrate-spring-with-hibernate-session-and-transaction-management. 

It would be good if you can add your comments in an answer, i would accept it. Thanks!